# Calculate the mean of R loop outputs

Tags: r, for-loop, mean

I need to calculate the means of an R for-loop output. For example:

```
for (x in 1:3) {
  print(x)
  vector <- c(sample(1:2, 200, replace = TRUE))
  print(vector)
  vmean <- (mean(vector))
  print(vmean)
}
```

This gives me:

```
\[1\] 1

\[1\] 1.535

\[1\] 2

\[1\] 1.495

\[1\] 3

\[1\] 1.545
```

How do I combine these three means to calculate the mean of the means?

Comment: at the end before you print the vmeans, include `vmeans[x] <- mean(vector)`

Comment: The mean of numbers in `1:2` cannot be 3 (5th printed value).

Answer (score 1):

We may create the `vmean` initialize and concatenate (or create a vector of  specific length and assign) to create a `vector` of `means` and then get the mean of `means`

```
vmean <- c()
for (x in 1:3) {
  print(x)
  vector <- c(sample(1:2, 200, replace = TRUE))
  #print(vector)
  vmean <- c(vmean, mean(vector))
  #print(vmean)
}
```

-output

```
> vmean
[1] 1.520 1.495 1.460
> mean(vmean)
[1] 1.491667
```

---

Or use `replicate` with `colMeans`

```
vmean <- colMeans(replicate(3, sample(1:2, 200, replace = TRUE)))
vmean
[1] 1.495 1.535 1.575
mean(vmean)
```

NOTE: values are different as there is no set seed

Comment: `replicate(3, mean(sample(1:2, 200, replace = TRUE)))` should also suffice

Comment: This so incredibly useful, thank you very much!